# How to change the background color in SumatraPDF reader?

Tags: colors, sumatra-pdf

How to change the background color. I would like to change it to something easier to read, is there an option to change this anywhere?

Answer (score 23):

If you run SumatraPDF with the command-line option `-bg-color 0xffff99` it will launch SumatraPDF with the new background color, and save the background color as your default.

The `0xffff99` part is the hex code for a lighter yellow.

Alternatively, the following command line option can be used:

> - -invert-colors
>
>   Swaps text and background color for most documents

Refer to https://github.com/sumatrapdfreader/sumatrapdf/wiki/Command-line-arguments for more information.

Refer to http://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/settings.html for more information regarding customizing colors in SumatraPDF-settings.txt (customizable by navigating to Menu -> Settings -> Advanced Settings)

Refer to https://i.stack.imgur.com/o047r.gif to create a shortcut to always open SumatraPDF in this mode.

SumatraPDF website: http://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/free-pdf-reader.html

Answer (score 15):

I found the solution. My setup is all black boarders and black start-up screen and total black in full-screen with white text.

Setting/Advanced Options, add line **GradientColors** to **FixedPageUI** then choose your hex color. Here is my setup for all black and white.

```
MainWindowBackground = #000000
EscToExit = false
ReuseInstance = false
UseSysColors = false
RestoreSession = true

FixedPageUI [
    TextColor = #ffffff
    BackgroundColor = #000000
    SelectionColor = #f5fc0c
    WindowMargin = 2 4 2 4
    PageSpacing = 4 4
    GradientColors = #000000
]
```

[image]

Comment: There is a much easier way to have a black background. Check https://superuser.com/a/1807787/1695392 .

Answer (score 3):

This can now be changed in the "Settings->Advanced Options...", you just need to edit the "MainWindowBackground" entry near the top.

Answer (score 3):

If you use dark theme for windows colors and want it used on SumatraPDF.  Find `SumatraPDF/SumatraPDF_settings.txt` and one of the first lines `UseSysColors` can be changed from `false` to `true`.

Comment: This worked for me for EPUB files, which were getting a pink (?) background by default.

Comment: There is a much easier way to have a black background. Check https://superuser.com/a/1807787/1695392 .

Answer (score 2):

You can apply Windows theme to your document using SumatraPDF options dialog. So, if you're using nice background color in Windows, Sumatra will use it too (works perfectly for me in classic Windows theme).

Comment: "You can apply Windows theme to your document using SumatraPDF options dialog." Fine, how?

Comment: @KJ Thank you for clarification. With my question, I meant that anonymous answer is incomplete by not providing the "how", and, as such, I downvoted it until it fixes his/her answer.

Answer (score 2):

Go to 'Settings' > 'Advanced Options...' It will open `SumatraPDF-settings.txt` file in the text editor. 
Then change the hex value of `BackgroundColor` option under `FixedPageUI` or any other corresponding *UI section.

More details http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/settings.html

Answer (score 2):

1. Press <kbd>i</kbd>;
2. Voilà! You now have inverted colors, effectively changing your background color to wathever the opposite of the previous one is.

Reference: [SumtraPDF GitHub, committed on Jul 15, 2021](https://github.com/sumatrapdfreader/sumatrapdf/commit/5332297c5518eb32ba429dbe47ac67f50d0a02ff).

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer I currently support SumatraPDF

Much has changed over the years so the -invert-colors command in latest 3.5 pre-release https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/prerelease is simply press the `I` key whilst viewing.

Command lines are depreciating for such limited color actions but can be found at https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/docs/Command-line-arguments

Many commands can be programmed and thus `T` is useful to test the theming changes but there are limitations so when using tear off tabs and other top bar enhancements it will still be non uniform color, (unless colorless)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's a command line option to invert colors:

`sumatrapdf.exe -invert-colors`

Basically for black-text-on-white it will produce white-text-on-black, while making other colors still readable just by inverting them also (in PDF-Xchange on contrary, if there are e.g. gray boxes, their contents might become unreadable afterwards).

Additionally, there's -set-color-range option which is more general:

`sumatrapdf.exe  -set-color-range 0x00dd00 0x000000`

This will produce green text on black background and scale other colors appropriately.

Documentation: <strike>http://code.google.com/p/sumatrapdf/wiki/CommandLineArguments</strike>
https://github.com/sumatrapdfreader/sumatrapdf/wiki/Command-line-arguments

Comment: No command line option is needed anymore. There is a much easier way to have a black background. Check https://superuser.com/a/1807787/1695392 .

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are right about the fixed UI setting, but my version of `sumatraPDF`, kept the book colour yellow, even if app was black.

So, I looked at the file more closely and found this in `ebook section` :

```
UseFixedPageUI = false
```

I just set it to `true` to fix it. You have to do same for all instances where you want it to set a custom colour.

Comment: If your answer is good, you'll gain reputations enough to post an image. For the time being post a link to image. That will be good & If needed, you can edit it later to directly post the image.

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately, I believe it's not possible.

The -bgcolor argument will only change the background color of the start-up screen.

Comment: thanks. i emailed the creater of reader to see if he can help

Comment: Wrong! It is possible, as other noted. Also, there is a very easy way to have a black background. Check https://superuser.com/a/1807787/1695392 .

Answer (score -2):

To change background color in last version of SumatraPDF go to **Settings -> Advanced Options**, change - **BackgroundColor** option in **FixedPageUI** part.
Like this:

```
FixedPageUI 
[
  TextColor = #000000 (change foreground text color)
  BackgroundColor = #f0f0f0 (change background color)
  SelectionColor = #f5fc0c
  WindowMargin = 1 0 1 0
  PageSpacing = 2 2
]
```

Comment: The `FixedPageUI` was already explained here on 2014. You are just duplicating the answer: https://superuser.com/a/714944/1695392

Answer (score -2):

If your EbookUI has UseFixedPageUI it will supercede that (and the other answers that change FixedPageUI won't work). So you then have to use:

```
EbookUI [
    FontName = Georgia
    FontSize = 12.5
    TextColor = #eeeeee
    BackgroundColor = #111111
    GradientColors = #000000
    UseFixedPageUI = false
]
```

Comment: The `UseFixedPageUI` was already explained here on 2018. You are just duplicating the answer: https://superuser.com/a/1325817/1695392

Answer (score -2):

Probably one needs white background and black text. For that use the following stps:

> settings >> Advanced option

on the top of the page paste the following code:

```
FixedPageUI [
    TextColor = #000000
    BackgroundColor = #FFFFFF
    SelectionColor = #f5fc0c
    WindowMargin = 2 4 2 4
    PageSpacing = 4 4
    HideScrollbars = false
]
```

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! How is this better than the other answers, some of them posted eleven years ago?

Comment: The `FixedPageUI` was already explained here on 2014. You are just duplicating the answer: https://superuser.com/a/714944/1695392